# How to set the mime-type of a new created file to application/json? C++

Tags: c++, json

I am creating a json string in C++ and save it to a file using `fstream`.

Here is the code for creating the file:

```
  string json="{ \"a\"= 1 }";

  fstream datei1("jsonfile.json",ios::out);
  file1 << json << endl;
  file1.close();
```

How could one set the mime-type to 'application/json'??

`file -i jsonfile.json` in linux shell gives me: `jsonfile.json: text/plain; charset=utf-8`

Comment: But the file *is* a plain text file. That it can be interpreted as something else is purely an application issue. Besides, few filesystem actually saves metadata like that in the actual file-system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[file command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file) try to guess the type of your file by reading it.

And read your file again: it **is** a plain text file. There is only a simple object stored, nothing that can lead to the application answer.

So without changing your file data, there is nothing you can do from your code to change [file command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file) answer.

Comment: how should the json text looks like to get 'application/json' or is this not possible?

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation of [file command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file):

> Causes the file command to output mime type strings rather than the
>   more traditional human readable ones. Thus it may say 'text/plain;
>   charset=us-ascii' rather than 'ASCII text'. In order for **this option
>   to work**, file changes the way it handles files recognized by the
>   command itself (such as many of the text file types, directories etc),
>   and makes use of an **alternative 'magic' file**. (See the FILES section,
>   below).
>
> `/usr/share/file/magic.mgc` Default compiled list of magic.
>   `/usr/share/file/magic` Directory containing default magic files.

You can read about magic files on the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Magic_numbers_in_files).
Also you can add your own signatures in `/etc/magic`.

But `*.json` is a plain text file, without any signatures, thus, probably, it's impossible to make OS think, that some file has `application/json` mime type without any hacks.